# Installing a fresh copy of Android on my rooted Galaxy Tab 10.1 2

Tags: updates, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I've got a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, which has been rooted, though it's still stock firmware. It has a whole bunch of problems right now with certain apps, e.g. it currently can't play any music (player crashes) and various other apps are pretty flaky. Anyway, I'd like to restore it back to stock, on the latest firmware. I'll probably root it again at a later date, but for now I'm not too fussed.

I've tried using the in-built update functionality (i.e. the "a new update is available" feature) but it reboots into CWM recovery and says that the signature verification failed.

How can I go about resetting the device, clearing out the junk, and updating it to the latest firmware? I'm not particularly fussed about any of the apps or settings that are on there.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar with my Nexus 7, but ended up just running another custom ROM to fix some of the problems. Would that be a possible option for you?

Comment: I'd much prefer to run stock.

Comment: That's fine. Just wondering if that might help fix your problem. Sorry, but I don't know how to do exactly what you want, or I would have done it myself!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) Once you've found a matching ROM, instructions usually go along.

Comment: Would doing a factory reset help?